# want to identify element with JSP core<c:if> tag using selenium webdriver using xpath or any other locators

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

```
<tr class="odd" role="row">
<td>PRODTUT020</td>
<td>Product for tours</td>
<td>
<td>
<ul class="icons-list">
<c:if test="true">
<li class="text-info-600">
<a href="edit-se-product_mst-90" title="View">
<i class="icon-eye"/>
</a>
</li>
</c:if>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
```

Above is the html body. Want to click on the icon-eye element. How do we identify this element using selenium locators?

Comment: I am not sure whether we can use xpath for locating JSP core tags<c:if>

Comment: Share code you've tried and current result

Comment: //td[text()='PRODTUT020']/../td[4]/ul          I tried this xpath. Unable to reach till i tag. Its giving me invalid xpath if i use //td[text()='PRODTUT020']/../td[4]/ul/c:if     for locating it

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//tr[td="PRODTUT020"]//i[@class="icon-eye"]
```

will select `i` elements with `@class` attribute value of `icon-eye` beneath the `tr` element whose `td` child has a string value of `PRODTUT020`.

Depending upon what's more invariant across your general cases, you might change `PRODTUT020` to `Product for tours` -- both work for the case you show.

It avoids having to name the namespaced element by skipping past it via `//`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch `i` inside `c:if` element you can use below expression

```
'//*[name()="c:if" and @test="true"]//i'
```

Comment: Thanks kjhughes i tried with your expression it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Andersson for your reply.

Comment: @HemanthKumar: You're welcome.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) the answer that has helped you the most.  (Note that [***this is my answer***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46525378/290085), however.)  Thanks.

Comment: This answer is helpful too (+1), but note that sometimes conditional, namespaced elements are removed/replaced at various points during runtime, depending upon their particular semantics.  For this reason, I think if possible it's better to [**avoid the issue via `//`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46525378/290085).